# run rails server and open http://localhost:3000 just have blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am a new guy with Rails, and I read *Ruby on Rails Tutorial* and made a sample_app. I use the Cloud9 before today. But I want to run this app in my Mac. So I push all file to Bitbucket and clone this repo in my Mac.

Then, I run `bundle install`and `rails db:migrate`, and don't get any errors. Also, `rails test` passes.

When I run `rails s`, I got this output:

```
> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie> at /Users/Shu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.5/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:57)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Sprockets method `register_engine` is deprecated.
Please register a mime type using `register_mime_type` then
use `register_compressor` or `register_transformer`.
https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#supporting-all-versions-of-sprockets-in-processors
 (called from block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie> at /Users/Shu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.5/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:58)
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

But when I open `http://localhost:3000`, it is blank,and the server doesn't have any change. These warnings also exist in Cloud9, but Cloud9 could open this site.

I try to `rails new` a new App, it works successfully. What should I do?

Comment: Hi Shucheng , can you please tell which version of sprockets gem are you using?

Comment: @Hizqeel sprockets version is 3.7.0

Comment: when you visit localhost :3000  do you see any log entries in the console ?

Comment: @Doon No,don't have any change.But I can use Ctrl+c exit it

Comment: well that is odd. normally you should have an entry showing the get.  do you have anything else listening on port 3000 on your computer or the like that could be intercepting the request, is your browser set to use a proxy?

Comment: @Doon Yeah,I have a auto proxy，But port is 8090

Comment: if you don't see a log showing it in the console. then Perhaps that proxy is getting in the way?  try opening up a command prompt type telnet localhost 3000 and see if you get a log entry

Comment: @Doon Maybe you're right.When I use 'rails s -P 3001'and I open localhost:3001,success! But couldn't open css file ,so just have some word.The console have some errors like some method undefined.(T＿T)

Comment: I have suggested an edit that, among other things, removes the Git tag, because this doesn't look like a Git issue. If I misunderstood, please [edit] your post to clarify.

Comment: @Doon What does it mean when rails insists on `* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000` even after I did `'rails s -P 3001`? (localhost:3001 can't be opened either)

Comment: @YCode try rails server -p  3001 , The lowercase p is the command line flag for port (case matters)

Comment: @Doon Now I get `Listening on tcp://localhost:3001`, though I am still getting a blank screen. But I learned something. Thanks!